# What error to throw when resource cannot be updated

Tags: rest, http

I'm implementing CRUD operations on a REST resource. Service can perform update only when the resource is in state 'X' and I need to show an error if resource state is not 'X'. What error should I throw if resource is not in state 'X'? 400 or 405 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What error should I throw if resource is not in state 'X'?

Either

- [405 Method Not Allowed](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)

> the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not    supported by the target resource.

- [409 Conflict](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)

> the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.

- [403 Forbidden](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

> the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it

Status codes are meta-data in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain.  It's a hint that we give to general purpose clients to help them [interpret](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) the rest of the information in the response.

A way of deciding which code to use is to compose the response body, and then consider which of the codes is a best fit.

---

In practice, there doesn't seem to be a lot of difference between these codes (405 is cacheable? shrug).  So you might do well to consider it an operator concern; which of these codes is going to make life easier for somebody reading the access log?